# oracle mobile server login issue

Tags: oracle, mobile

I have installed Oracle Mobile server (DMS_12.1.0.0.0_WINDOWS) on glassfish ogs-3.1.2.2-windows-ml all on Windows 7 x64 and the backend database is Oracle 12.1.0.2 on Virtual machine Redhat linux 7.2 . Everything went fine , but I can not login into the Mobile manager (http://pcname:8080/mobile/console/login.uix) , it doesnt accept the password of the administrator user although I am confident it is the correct password. I reinstalled everything again but same issue . Is there any way to reset the password of the administrator account .

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Did you include any '@' character in the password - it is possible that the database mobile server matched that to the connection string.